# Filtering a table based on the marked choices in a set of collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 tables. One of products, one of clients and one of sales. The Sale table is associated with the other two in a many-to-one manner (one client can have many sales, one product can be sold many times).

I have a controller where the contents of the Sale table are displayed, and I'd like to include two groups of checkboxes, one for clients and the other for products. The idea is that the user checks the boxes of the ones they'd like to include in the table (which can be one, all or none).

For instance, if I wanted to know all the sales of the Client 1, I'd mark the checkbox for Client 1. If I wanted a list of products of Product 3, I'd mark Product 3. If I wanted all the sales to Client 1 and of Product 3, I'd mark both. And so on. I think the idea in that aspect is clear.

I'm currently trying to use a form_tag, that includes two collection_check_boxes. I've managed to display both of them, but I don't know how to send the data back into the view to filter the contents.

This is how I have the code on the view (haml):

```
=form_tag do
  %table{:id => 'options_table', :class => 'tablex'}
      %th='Products'
      %th='Clients'
    %tr
      %td= collection_check_boxes(:product,'',@products,'id','name')
      %td= collection_check_boxes(:client,'',@clients,'id','name')
```

@products and @clients were previously populated with ".all" in the controller.

I'd like to note that I haven't specified a controller 'action' for the form yet, as I was having trouble to create the proper route. Ideally, I'd like to send it back to the index, where the @sales object would then do the filtering, based on the arrays previously marked.

Any pointer is greatly appreciated. I'm new to rails and still trying to find my way, so I apologise is this is too obvious.

Thank you.